# How do I write a shorthand for a datatype in Scala

Tags: scala

How do I write shorthand for a datatype?
For example. 
lets say instead of `List[Integer]`, I would rather type `Integers`

instead of this

```
def processNumbers(input:List[Integer]):List[Integer] = ...
```

to

```
def processNumbers(input:Integers):Integers = ...
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a [type alias](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/definition-details.html#type-definition).

```
type Integers = List[Int]  // scala.Int is preferred over java.lang.Integer
```

That being said, this isn't really a good use for them. `List[Int]` is very clear to other scala developers, wheres your type `Integers` provides no extra information and so will detract from the readability of your code over time.

A use of type aliases that would improve your code's readability though would be something like

```
type UserId = Int
def processUsers(ids: List[UserId]): Foo
```

In this case it provides extra information to the reader vs

```
def processUsers(ids: List[Int]): Foo
```

Using that kind of type alias also will allow you to gradually make your code more type-safe over time by changing the definition from a type alias to a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

```
case class UserId(value: Int) extends AnyVal
```

You won't need to change the method signatures of anything already having "`UserId`", but this will let the compiler assist you in making sure you don't do something like

```
val ids: List[Int] = getBlogPostIds()
val foo = processUsers(ids) // Oops, those Ints are for blog posts, not users
```

Using the value class approach, a mistake like that becomes a compiler error. Used pervasively it adds quite a lot of guidance in writing correct code.

```
val ids: List[BlogPostId] = getBlogPostIds
val foo = processUsers(ids) // Compile error; BlogPostId != UserId
```